# How can I get stacked plots on the panel in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, uniformgrid, scottplot

I  was wondering if you could help me with something.
I'm trying to get stacked plots like this picture.

[image: Stacked plots]

I'm using `UniformGrid` to try to get something like this, but it's not correct.

```xml
<UniformGrid x:Name="plots" Rows="2">
            <StackPanel x:Name="plot1" IsEnabled="False" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <Grid MinWidth="300" MinHeight="300">
                    <WpfPlot x:Name="hr_graph"/>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel x:Name="plot2" IsEnabled="False" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <Grid MinWidth="300" MinHeight="300" >
                    <WpfPlot x:Name="sat_graph"/>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel x:Name="plot3" IsEnabled="False" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <Grid MinWidth="300" MinHeight="300">
                    <WpfPlot x:Name="pul_graph"/>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel x:Name="plot4" IsEnabled="False" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <Grid MinWidth="300" MinHeight="300">
                    <WpfPlot x:Name="per_graph" />
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </UniformGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make this container just a generic `ItemsControl`, and change its `ItemsPanel` according to number of visible panels.
For example:

```xml
<DataTemplate x:Name="PartsLayout">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Slider x:Name="Slider" Margin="6" Value="4" Minimum="1" Maximum="4" TickFrequency="1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="6" Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=Slider}" />
        </Grid>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="Items" Grid.Row="1">
            <StackPanel x:Name="Part1" Background="Yellow" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
            <StackPanel x:Name="Part2" Background="Green" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
            <StackPanel x:Name="Part3" Background="Red" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
            <StackPanel x:Name="Part4" Background="Blue" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Rows="2" Columns="2" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value, ElementName=Slider}" Value="3">
            <Setter TargetName="Part4" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            <Setter TargetName="Items" Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        </Grid>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value, ElementName=Slider}" Value="2">
            <Setter TargetName="Part4" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            <Setter TargetName="Part3" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            <Setter TargetName="Items" Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Rows="1" Columns="2" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value, ElementName=Slider}" Value="1">
            <Setter TargetName="Part4" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            <Setter TargetName="Part3" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            <Setter TargetName="Part2" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            <Setter TargetName="Items" Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Grid />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

That's in plain xaml - I have a slider where you select number of panels to view and according to its value, I change `Visibility` of different panels and `ItemsPanel` as well.
If you are changing `Visibility` in code-behind, then you can change `ItemsPanel` of `ItemsControl` in code-behind as well.
So, when you need single panel you set it to simple `Grid`, if two panels: `UniformGrid 1x2`, if three panels: `Grid` with two equal rows and two equal columns and pay attention on `Grid.Row`, `Grid.Column`, `Grid.ColumnSpan` properties defined on panels. For four panels we use `UniformGrid 2x2`.
Hope, that helps.

**Important**: This will only work if your panels should always be in same order, and for example `Part3` can't be visible if `Part2' is hidden. Otherwise, it's a bit more tricky - you will need to dynamically assigned content to parts.

**UPD**: To view `DataTemplate` on window you can use `ContentControl`:

```xml
<ContentControl Content="1">
   <ContentControl.ContentTemlate>
      ... Put DataTemplate here ...
   </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I never used DataTemplate and when I'm trying to start ur code I get window with text "System.Windows.DataTemplate". Do I understand correctly that some kind of data binding is needed?

Comment: `DataTemplate` is widely used in MVVM approach. I've updated the answer with usage sample. However, it will help you only as idea - you should make changes to `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel` in code behind. If you add your code, I can help you to update it

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! I just wanted to see what it would like. Now I can update my code myself)